# Ruby On Rails 5 Error expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**THIS IS MY CODE**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.ratings
       Movie.select(:rating).distinct.inject([]) { la, ml a.push m.rating}
   end  
end
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING**

```
app/models/movie.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,

expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' distinct.inject([]) { la, ml a.push m.rating} ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap block arguments in `|`, not `l`

```
Movie.select(:rating).distinct.inject([]) { |a, m| a.push m.rating}
```